# How to Call a WCF service in java

Tags: java

I am new to Java and I need to call a WCF. Is there any way in Java that I do not need to consume it and can directly hit the url to get response?

Comment: Please provide the sample how yare you calling WCF, via browser or any other tool ? might be java guy don't knoe WCF.

Comment: Actually we just created a WCF in .Net and one of our client is trying to call it in Java but they are unable to do so. They are getting error for operation contract mismatch

Answer (score 1):

You can consume the webservice using Java there are different frameworks to make your job easier, like [AXIS](http://axis.apache.org/axis/) and [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/)

Look at following article for more details

[Consuming WCF services with Java](http://www.hoonzis.com/consuming-wcf-services-with-java-client/)

Answer (score 0):

For Java client application, I think you can generate the proxy class from Eclipse and invoke the call to WCF service.

The general steps are as follows:

1. Prepare the WCF service and run the service.
2. Create the Java client application in Eclipse IDE, and name the project, like WCFClientApp in this case.

You can follow this blog for better practical understanding
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/777036/Consuming-WCF-Service-in-Java-Client

Comment: I am able to do it by creating a webservice client, but is there any other way through which I can directly call it by making request

Answer (score 0):

You can make a direct call using HttpURLConnection in the Java.Net library

```
URL url = new URL("https://{ApiEndpoint}/v2/EmailMarketing.svc/SendEmail");
HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
http.setRequestMethod("POST");
http.setDoOutput(true);
http.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
http.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

String data = "{\"Id\": 78912, \"Quantity\": 1, \"Price\": 19.00}";

byte[] out = data.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

OutputStream stream = http.getOutputStream();
stream.write(out);

System.out.println(http.getResponseCode() + " " + 
http.getResponseMessage());
http.disconnect();
```